# How add placeholder on editText empty characters

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have an editText that has a limit of 4 characters

I want to add a place holder in all the empty characters

Is similar to a password input

○ for empty characters and ● for already taken

Examples:

Pin is 112 => Result in EditText ●●●○

Pin: 12 => EditText ●●○○

Pin: 1234 => EditText ●●●●

Comment: why not add a `addTextChangedListener` and change your ui based on char change ?

Comment: @makkhaygurung it's not entirely that easy, because you also have to keep track of the ACTUAL input too

Comment: Best way in my opinion is to use Custom View : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

Comment: I am not the most experienced Android developper, but I have been trying to fiddle this for a few hours now and it is actually hard. Using addTextChangedListener makes it very hard to handle selection focus and keep track of the actual text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing a simple custom view that does what I wanted. Is a little outdated but can be tweaked easily.

https://github.com/waveduke/PinView

I hope it helps anyone that has the same problem :)